# HTML <datalist> feature not triggered in Microsoft Edge

Tags: html, microsoft-edge

I'm testing the HTML's `datalist` tag on Microsoft Edge.

It works fine but the problem with Edge is that there is an option to close the autofill dialog by clicking the "Don't show saved information".

If a user were to accidentally close it, the autocomplete feature is not triggered anymore even after refreshing the page.

The only way to re-activate the feature is by editing the browser's settings manually.

In contrast, Chrome and Firefox do show the autocomplete in modal that do not have a close option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need to set your input to *autocompleteOff*, so Microsoft Edge lost his control trying to show it's popup feature.

```html
<form action="#" method="get">
  <label for="autocompleteOff">Use Microsoft Edge as your browser and select on the list:</label>
  <input type="text" autocomplete="off" list="autocompleteOff"
id="myId" name="myName" placeholder="Placeholder here" />
  <datalist id="autocompleteOff">
    <option value="Selection 1">
    <option value="Selection 2">
    <option value="Selection 3">
    <option value="Selection 4">
    <option value="Selection 5">
  </datalist>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

*Use Microsoft Edge when trying this, so you can check if it's working!*

Answer (score 0):

I spent the better part of a whole day trying to sort this exact issue out.
Bizarrely, changing the placeholder text of the form/input element into something the browser can't parse as some sort of instruction prevents the saved information box from showing up, thus eliminating the chance the user can click 'x' breaking any autocomplete behavior you want to programm.

having:

```
placeholder="Enter Location"
placeholder="Postcode"
placeholder="Input Country"
```

all trigger the histroy box to appear in Edge.

having:

```
placeholder="Edge is f**ing stupid"
```

blocks the box from showing up. So strange.